# Poisson distribution: how to calculate the expected number of zeros in the presence of an exposure term

Tags: poisson-distribution, offset

I have a dataset each with a line for different products, a count of sales and a number of days on sale. I estimated a Poisson regression to predict sales with an offset term of number of days on sale, but it was over-dispersed and I'm considering using a zero-inflated model. I used the `DHARMa` package's `testZeroInflation` function - my model failed the test and clearly has too many zeros.

However, I would like to verify this for myself manually. This [Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72238/how-can-i-fit-a-zero-inflated-poisson-model-with-only-offset-without-coefficien) sets out how to do that for a simple dataset with counts only, and I tried something similar:

```
length(myData$sales[myData$sales==0]))   # number of zero sales
P0 <- ppois(0, mean(myData$sales / myData$daysOnSale))
P0 * length(myData$sales) # expected number of zeros given Poisson distribution
```

This test showed I had far *fewer* zeros than expected. My interpretation is that this would be correct if the exposure term - daysOnSale - were 1 in all cases, but actually it varies widely: from 1 to several hundred.

Is there a (straightforward) way to account for exposure when calculating the expected number of zeros?

Comment: Could you post a full account of your data and results.

Comment: You can add up the expected zeros for each case, with its individual exposure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes. With $\lambda=\text{expected number of sales in one day}$ and $n=\text{exposure}$, $X$ the total number of sales, then $X$ is distributed poisson with expectation $n\cdot\lambda$, so
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=0) = e^{-n\cdot \lambda}
$$

Comment: Thanks @kjetilbhalvorsen, so would the final answer be to calculate this probability of observing zero for each row and then sum across the rows? As in, `myData$probZeroSales <- exp(-1 * myData$daysOnSale * mean(myData$sales / myData$daysOnSale))`, `sum(myData$probZeroSales)`

Comment: That looks ok...